# Error when the lambda expression is taking two arguments in Python

Tags: python, lambda, python-3.6

I am new to Python and practicing basics. I am using a lambda expression to take two arguments and performing square operations on them (eg: `var ** 2`). The two arguments are coming from the `zip(list1, list2)`. I am getting `TypeError` for this. I tried searching for the solution but didn't get any. I even tried writing lambda arguments in parenthesis (eg: `lambda (v1,v2):`) but that threw `SyntaxError`.

Below is the python code:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4]
list2 = [5,6,7,8]
print ( list(map(lambda v1,v2: (v1**2, v2**2), list(zip(list1, list2)))) )
```

Error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-241-e93d37efc752> in <module>()
      1 list1 = [1,2,3,4]
      2 list2 = [5,6,7,8]
----> 3 print ( list(map(lambda v1,v2: (v1**2, v2**2), list(zip(list1, list2)))) )

TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'v2'
```

Comment: Just put brackets after v1 and v2 like this `print ( list(map(lambda (v1,v2): (v1**2, v2**2), list(zip(list1, list2)))) )`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're giving a single list as argument to `map`, thus `map` calls your `lambda` with one element of the list at a time - that is **one** argument, even though it is a tuple. What you probably want is:

```
print ( list(map(lambda v: (v[0]**2, v[1]**2), zip(list1, list2))) )
```

so that your item from the list is passed as a sole argument to `lambda`.
If you insist on the two-argument `lambda`, discard `zip` and pass your lists directly to `map` as separate arguments:

```
print ( list(map(lambda v1,v2: (v1**2, v2**2), list1, list2)) )
```

Comment: the `list` on the `zip` is not needed

Comment: Hi Blotosmetek that really helped. Make perfect sense. Thanks. Appreciated.

Comment: Yes @Ev.Kounis that works too. Casted to list as I was not sure whether the zip object would be returned or not as per the new changes in the Python-3

Comment: I like the 2nd one much better, it's one of the few cases where `map()` is still actually useful in Python (rather than a list comp). anyway +1

Answer (score 0):

In your print, `map` will cal the function lambda on a list of tuples (as `list(zip(list1, list2))` produce a list of tuples).

So for instance you can do :

```
print(list(map(lambda(v1,v2): (v1**2, v2**2), list(zip(list1, list2)))))
```

Your lambda function will use the tuple (v1,v2) as parameters, instead of two parameters.